# Menu that Updates Panel on Webpage

Tags: menu

I'm looking to create a menu that updates a panel on a page, but I'm not sure what it's called to research and build on my wordpress site.
I would appreciate any help on figuring out how to accomplish this.
Thank you!

The best example I know of is on NerdWallet.

[image: In menu that updates panel]